# Why does memkind and numactl improve program performance a lot?

Tags: memory, parallel-processing, openmp

According to the course https://www.coursera.org/learn/parallelism-ia/home/welcome, there is one example which tried to illustrate the improvement from memkind API by using `hbw_posix_memalign((void**)&pixel, 64, sizeof(P)*width*height);` I think this API only provides us aligned memory allocation. I do not know why this can help improve the GPflops so much as the following shows. [image]

The part of coding is as the following. Here the memory which stores img_in is allocated by memkind API.

```
template<typename P>
void ApplyStencil(ImageClass<P> & img_in, ImageClass<P> & img_out) {
  
  const int width  = img_in.width;
  const int height = img_in.height;

  P * in  = img_in.pixel;
  P * out = img_out.pixel;

#pragma omp parallel for
  for (int i = 1; i < height-1; i++)
#pragma omp simd
    for (int j = 1; j < width-1; j++) {
      P val = -in[(i-1)*width + j-1] -   in[(i-1)*width + j] - in[(i-1)*width + j+1] 
    -in[(i  )*width + j-1] + 8*in[(i  )*width + j] - in[(i  )*width + j+1] 
    -in[(i+1)*width + j-1] -   in[(i+1)*width + j] - in[(i+1)*width + j+1];

      val = (val < 0   ? 0   : val);
      val = (val > 255 ? 255 : val);

      out[i*width + j] = val;
    }
  
}
```

My questions are as the follwing:

1. Is it only because we can use less memory operation to get our data and then we can improve the performance almost 5 times?
2. In terms of numaclt, based on the linux documentation, it allows us to bind the processes with specific nodes or cpus. When we use the command `numactl -m 1`, we can get the improvement 5 times. I not sure if the improvement comes from NUMA communication delay.

Comment: In the chart, it looks like the bar for "multi-threaded" was running in the DRAM, while the higher performance seems to come ffrom HBM (high-bandwidth memory). As a wild guess: if this is a Knights Landing processor the ratio of 5x between DRAM and HBM sounds about right.

Comment: @MichaelKlemm You are right. So the improvement mainly comes from the hardware.